# rostopic pub message with UInt16 fields etc

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a message type as follows:

```
# LegoNXTROS_Status message
# Defines the protocol for publishing the NXT robot's status.
#
uint16 leftMotorEncoder
uint16 rightMotorEncoder
uint8 sonarSensor
bool leftTouchSensor
bool rightTouchSensor
```

When I use `rostopic pub -1 /LegoNXTROS_Status nxt/LegoNXTROS_Status 1, 1, 120, false, false`

roscore responds repeatedly with: `[WARN] [WallTime: 1415504044.156096] Inbound TCP/IP connection failed: field leftMotorEncoder must be unsigned integer type` and the message doesn't get through.

Can someone clarify what I'm doing wrong?
Cheers,
Nap

@ahendrix:  Thanks.  I will add that to my 'cheat' sheet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197059/rostopic-pub-message-with-uint16-fields-etc/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect `rostopic pub` is confused by the commas in your command. Maybe try without them?

```
rostopic pub -1 /LegoNXTROS_Status nxt/LegoNXTROS_Status 1 1 120 false false
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1